# Swingbench while installation Java error occuring

Tags: java, schema, oracle12c

I'm trying to install Swingbench but while I click the Next button I got an error

***Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"***

Did anyone face this kind of problem?

My installation process:
**CMD**

***STEPS)***

```
cd /d E:\swingbench\winbin
set PATH=C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk\jre\bin
oewizard
```

I tried different Java versions not helped

```
E:\swingbench\winbin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same  problem -  I don't know the exact reason for the error but found a solution by giving fully qualified name and changing the connection type to 'thin'  as attached

[image: Swingbench screenshot]

Comment: It is better to post code responses rather than links to pictures.